Display list of acronyms in small caps using {glossaries} package
I've read through the entry-level explanation of the glossaries package  and found how to successfully display my acronyms in small-caps in my body text as shown in the following MWE:
% !TEX program = lualatex 

\documentclass[twoside, a4paper]{report}

% Packages
\usepackage[acronyms, style=indexgroup, nonumberlist, nopostdot]{glossaries} 

% Glossary entries
\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={LaTeX is a document preparation system}
}
\newglossaryentry{word}
{
    name=word,
    description={word is an entry in the glossary}
}

% Acronym entries
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short} % 'sc' : used to show acronyms in small-caps.
\newacronym
    {svm} 
    {svm}
    {support vector machine} 
\newacronym
    {aa} 
    {aa} 
    {another acronym} 

\makenoidxglossaries % sort glossary in alphabetical order (caution for latin extended words)

\begin{document}

\section{Text with acronyms}
First use: \gls{svm}. Second use: \gls{svm}. \\
First use: \gls{aa}. Second use: \gls{aa}.

\section{Text with glossary entries}
First use: \gls{latex}. Second use: \gls{word}.

\printnoidxglossaries % list all entries

\end{document}

However, when running the command to create the list of acronyms, they are shown in lowercase (only in the list). As seen in the following screenshots :


Is there a way to display the list of acronyms in smallcaps while keeping the main glossary (ie. glossary of words in normal caps) ?
For info, this is how the main glossary looks -and ideally should look- like :

Sidenote : I have seen the following post. However, I think that this solution would set all entries in all-caps (meaning not only acronym) and on top of that, assigning the option ⁠small-caps ⁠to the package glossaries does not work for me.
Thanks in advance for your help ;)
